# HTML radio buttons looks square in iphone

Tags: html, iphone

I have added radio buttons in my mobile site but it looks in square shape with gradient fill specifically on iPhone browser while clicking on it it shows selected radio button with light border around it. On other phone browsers it looks proper like on windows and android phones without border only radio button.

I have tried to control this by CSS but not works.

```
input[type="radio"] {border: none!important; background-color: transparent; appearance: radio; -moz-appearance: radio; -webkit-appearance: radio;}
```

This is the actual button code.

```
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Quality_1" value="1">
```

### Can any body help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You must have CSS styles that are being applied to your radio button that are:

1. setting a border radius (to a low radius value eg. 2px) - this causes the square effect
2. setting a background colour - to give the gradient colour.

For example, you may have something like this in your CSS:

```
input { 
    border-radius:2px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(186,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,59,59) 49%);
}
```

You will need to either override it with CSS styles as you have tried to do, or else make your CSS style affecting the radio button not affect it.

For example, by changing your CSS class to the following, it won't apply the class to radio buttons:

```
input:not([type='radio'])
    border-radius:2px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(186,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,59,59) 49%);
}
```

Note: There is an error in your CSS example, which is probably why you still have a background colour - there should be a space between `none` and `!important`:

```
border: none !important;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this style to your radio button

```
border-radius:12px;
```